# Exception in Pyspark Structured Streaming from Kafka Source

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

**Environment:** Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12.18, openjdk 11.0.20.1

I'm trying to stream data from a Kafka source, but getting an exception from Spark.
It seems like this is often due to dependency version mismatches, but my package version matches my environment.

The Kafka server is running and I can see data (kafka_2.12-3.5.1/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic stockPrices)

**Bash Command:**

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.0 ./test.py
```

**PySpark Script (test.py):**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("KafkaStreamToRDD") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "stockPrices") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()
```

**Exception:**

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.<init>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:601)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.<clinit>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaSourceProvider$$validateStreamOptions(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:338)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.sourceSchema(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.loadInternal(DataStreamReader.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:145)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        ... 22 more
```

I've checked my dependency versions and reinstalled Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to clean up my spark jars folder. I had multiple versions of a couple jars (spark-avro_2.12-3.5.0 and spark-avro_2.12:3.4.1). Spark was picking up the wrong wrong ones.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, config "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.2" is enough but sometimes I need to provide all jars to make it work. (Hope it helps guys!)

org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.2,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.8.1,org.apache.spark:spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.2